# CSS Spacing Issue and Lag When Scrolling Down Into New Background Images

Tags: html, css, background-image, parallax

I am currently building a Homepage using the CSS `background-attachment` property to create a scrolling background effect.

I have multiple backgrounds with a content section in between each one. After the first content section, there is a long small white space before the next background image and I am not sure how to get rid of that space.

[image: SS]

---

Another issue I am having is with the actual performance of the page.

When I scroll to a new image, there is about a one second or two second delay before it will actually show the image. In other words, the screen actually freezes for a few seconds when attempting to scroll to a new `background`.

I don't think this matters at all but I am building this as an ASP.NET MVC web application.

Here is my HTML:

```
<body>   
        <main class="cd-main-content">
            <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-1">
                <div class="cd-intro">

                </div>
            </div> <!-- cd-fixed-bg -->

            <div class="cd-scrolling-bg cd-color-2">            
                <div class="cd-container">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing  elit. Dolore incidunt suscipit similique, dolor corrupti cumque qui consectetur 
                    </p>
                </div> <!-- cd-container -->
            </div> <!-- cd-scrolling-bg -->

            <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-2">
                <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
            </div> <!-- cd-fixed-bg -->

            <div class="cd-scrolling-bg cd-color-3">
                <div class="cd-container">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore incidunt suscipit similique, dolor corrupti cumque qui consectetur autem laborum fuga quas ipsam doloribus sequi, mollitia, repellendus sapiente 

                    </p>
                </div> <!-- cd-container -->
            </div> <!-- cd-scrolling-bg -->

            <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-3">
                <div class="cd-container">
                    <p>


                    </p>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- cd-fixed-bg -->


        </main> <!-- cd-main-content -->

    </body>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
    body, html, main {
    /* important */
    height: 100%;
}

.cd-fixed-bg {
    min-height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-1 {
  background-image: url('../Images/portfolio1.jpg');
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-2 {
  background-image: url('../Images/portfolio2.jpg');
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-3 {
  background-image: url('../Images/portfolio3.jpg');
}
.cd-scrolling-bg {
    position:relative;
    min-height: 70%;
    padding: 4em 0;
    line-height: 2.7;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0%;
    bottom: 0%;
    left: 0%;
}
.cd-intro {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: inherit;
    z-index: 100;
    text-align:center;
    height: 400px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    color: white;
    width: 600px;
    margin-left: -300px;
    font-size: 45px;
    font-family:'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
.cd-container
{
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 768px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
.cd-scrolling-bg.cd-color-3 {
    background-color: #b4d7a8;
    color: #3d3536;
}
.cd-scrolling-bg.cd-color-2 {
    background-color: #b4d7a8;
    color: #3d3536;
}
.cd-scrolling-bg.cd-color-3 {
    background-color: #b4d7a8;
    color: #3d3536;
}
```

Comment: have you seen the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The white-space is created by `p` and `h2`.

In HTML the paragraphs and headings have `margin` by default, so reset either all or just the one you need it.

I removed the `left:50%` from your first  `cd-intro` due to creating horizontal scrollbar.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
body,
html,
main {
  /* important */
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}
.cd-fixed-bg {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-1 {
  background-image: url('//lorempixel.com/900/900/sports');
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-2 {
  background-image: url('//lorempixel.com/900/900/animals');
}
.cd-fixed-bg.cd-bg-3 {
  background-image: url('//lorempixel.com/900/900/city');
}
.cd-scrolling-bg {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 70%;
  padding: 4em 0;
  line-height: 2.7;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  left: 0%;
}
.cd-intro {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: inherit;
  z-index: 100;
  text-align: center;
  height: 400px;
  color: white;
  width: 600px;
  font-size: 45px;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
.cd-container {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 768px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.cd-scrolling-bg.cd-color-3 {
  background-color: #b4d7a8;
  color: #3d3536;
}
.cd-scrolling-bg.cd-color-2 {
  background-color: #b4d7a8;
  color: #3d3536;
}
.cd-scrolling-bg.cd-color-3 {
  background-color: #b4d7a8;
  color: #3d3536;
}
h2, p {
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<main class="cd-main-content">
  <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-1">
    <div class="cd-intro">
      some text
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- cd-fixed-bg -->

  <div class="cd-scrolling-bg cd-color-2">
    <div class="cd-container">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore incidunt suscipit similique, dolor corrupti cumque qui consectetur
      </p>
    </div>
    <!-- cd-container -->
  </div>
  <!-- cd-scrolling-bg -->

  <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-2">
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
  </div>
  <!-- cd-fixed-bg -->

  <div class="cd-scrolling-bg cd-color-3">
    <div class="cd-container">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolore incidunt suscipit similique, dolor corrupti cumque qui consectetur autem laborum fuga quas ipsam doloribus sequi, mollitia, repellendus sapiente

      </p>
    </div>
    <!-- cd-container -->
  </div>
  <!-- cd-scrolling-bg -->

  <div class="cd-fixed-bg cd-bg-3">
    <div class="cd-container">
      <p>


      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- cd-fixed-bg -->


</main>
<!-- cd-main-content -->
```